# Hide Matplotlib Text during save

Tags: text, matplotlib

I have a 'Paused' Matplotlib text to tell the user the graph is paused. This works great, but I do not want the word "paused" to show when printing or saving.

```
figPausedText = fig.text(0.5, 0.5,'Paused', horizontalalignment='center',
    verticalalignment='center',
    transform=ax.transAxes,
    alpha = 0.25,
    size='x-large')
```

What's the best way to hide the Paused text when saving/printing? I'm happy to `set_text('')` if I can bind to all save and print commands. I particularly want to make sure it works when a user clicks the NavigationToolbar2TkAgg toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
figPausedText = fig.text(...)
def my_save(fig, * args, **kwargs):
     figPausedText.set_visible(False)
     fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
     figPausedText.set_visible(True)
```

If you want to get really clever, you can monkey patch your `Figure` object:

```
import types

figPausedText = fig.text(...)
# make sure we have a copy of the origanal savefig
old_save = matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig
# our new function which well hide and then re-show your text
def my_save(fig, *args, **kwargs):
     figPausedText.set_visible(False)
     ret = old_save(fig, *args, **kwargs)
     figPausedText.set_visible(True)
     return ret
# monkey patch just this instantiation  
fig.savefig = types.MethodType(my_save, fig)
```

or if you need this to work through the tool bar

```
import types

figPausedText = fig.text(...)
# make sure we have a copy of the origanal print_figure
old_print = fig.canvas.print_figure # this is a bound function
# if we want to do this right it is backend dependent
# our new function which well hide and then re-show your text
def my_save(canvas, *args, **kwargs):
     figPausedText.set_visible(False)
     ret = old_print(*args, **kwargs) # we saved the bound function, so don't need canvas
     figPausedText.set_visible(True)
     return ret
# monkey patch just this instantiation  
fig.canvas.print_figure = types.MethodType(my_save, fig.canvas)
```

Comment: This looks good, but unfortunately the my_save was not called when the NavigationToolbar2TkAgg save button was clicked. How can this work with the NavigationToolbar2TkAgg? I tried variants from the [saving documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.NavigationToolbar2.save_figure)

Comment: Then monkey patch `canvas.print_figure` instead

Comment: Also, edit your question to indicate that you want this to work through the gui tool bar.